# General Search Query in Solr

Tags: solr

I have tried to run a single term search in Solr 9.0 through by using

q=term

(e.g. http://localhost:8983/solr/windowstest/select?indent=true&q.op=OR&q=yelp).

I've noticed that older versions of Solr were able to handle such a request but now I can only search all fields for that term by adding using OR

q=id:*yelp* OR subject:*yelp* OR body:*yelp*

(e.g. http://localhost:8983/solr/windowstest/select?indent=true&q.op=OR&q=id%3A*yelp*%20OR%20subject%3A*yelp*%20OR%20body%3A*yelp*).

Is there a way to not have to indicate the fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no setting for "searching all fields"; however, what is usually done is to have a single field as the `copyField` destination for all fields. You can do this by defining a catch-all field (by default named `_text_`, and then configuring `<copyField src="*" dest="_text_">` - making the content of all the fields get copied into `_text_`.

You can then set the default search field (i.e. where there isn't a field name given) with the `df` parameter in the query - the default field.

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/windowstest/selectq.op=OR&q=yelp&df=_text_
```

If you want to set this as the default, [you configure it as a default parameter in `solrconfig.xml` under the specific request handler](https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/configuration-guide/requesthandlers-searchcomponents.html#defaults-appends-and-invariants):

```
<requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
  <lst name="defaults">
    <str name="df">_text_</str>
    <int name="rows">10</int>
  </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

.. or [by using initparams](https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/configuration-guide/initparams.html):

```
<initParams path="/update/**,/query,/select,/tvrh,/elevate,/spell">
  <lst name="defaults">
    <str name="df">_text_</str>
  </lst>
</initParams>
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I realized my mistake was that I added <copyField source="*" dest="_text_"> AFTER indexing data. I created a new core and set the copyfield before indexing and it works fine. Thanks again.